# C++ Setup own cast rules for template classes/structures

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, casting

is it possible to implement your own cast rules and to make the compiler give a warning about it rather than an error?

I'm currently working with SFML (doesn't really matter if you don't know it) and it has a simple Vector2 structure like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector2 {
    Vector2<T>(T,T);
    T x,y;
}
```

Now I'm using this quite often and would like to setup a custom cast rule for this structure, since I can't modify the source code. I currently have a function that needs a `Vector2<int>`, but a function I use returns a `Vector2<unsigned int>` and the compiler doesn't seem to be able to cast the one into the other which is a bit weird.

I know I can use the casts (and `static_cast` works), but it seems a bit too elaborate for a a simple conversion like this, and a bit stupid that I can't test my program because of this. So what I'm probably searching for are compiler commands that can setup such cast rules.

Comment: I assume static_cast not working in this case? Have you tried:
std::memcpy; Or maybe reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @Telkitty read the last paragraph :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this (both ways require you to modify the definition of `Vector2`). You can add a non-explicit constructor that performs the conversion:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector2 {
    template<typename U>
    Vector2(Vector2<U> const& u) : x(u.x), y(u.y){}
    Vector2(T x,T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    T x,y;
};
```

or you can add a non-explicit type-cast operator:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector2 {
    template<typename U>
    operator Vector2<U>(){
        return Vector2<U>(x,y);
    }
    Vector2(T x,T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    T x,y;
};
```

Comment: Hmm, good to know this method. But as I said it's from an external library which I can't modify so this won't work for me...

Comment: @Didii: In that case, just make yourself some helper `cast_to` functions that perform the conversions. It's a little uglier, but it is impossible to magically add functionality to a `class` without modifying it.

Comment: well, the conversion is perfectly possible with `static_cast`. The only thing I wanted to achieve is that I do not have to solve all these conversions before able to test the program. I suppose I'm looking for commands for the compiler instead of C++ code. Thanks anyway for the help, I've up-voted your answer :)